# Is it possible to use Microsoft Flow to post a file to sharepoint a folder that varies by user name?

Tags: sharepoint, office365

Lets say we have this Sharepoint folder structure

```
SharepointSite:
              | 
              |___PersonA
              |___PersonB
```

How to configure a flow to post to the folder relative to the user that executed it
so if PersonA executed the flow, a file will be posted to the folder named PersonA and if PersonB executed it, the file will go into PersonB ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.
The way this is achieved is by capturing the "PersonA", "PersonB" and storing it to a variable at the start of the Flow.
You would then use "Create file" in a similar way to what is in the image (you variable where Output is) and it will go to the folder path you have specified. It can even create the folder path as new.
[Create file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSWzy.png)